# Why is adding event to button not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to add an EventListener to a button. Here is my code:

```
<button data-id="g/incider/perry">Kaufen</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var button = document.getElementById('g/incider/perry');
  button.addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() { 
      alert("test");      
    },
    false
  );
</script>
```

But the alert is not shown when the button is clicked.

Comment: You've assigned a `data-id` to the element, but trying to find an element with `id`.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are new to the Javascript so will help you out here.

As you see your element `<button data-id="g/incider/perry">Kaufen</button>` has `data-id` attribute mentioned but you want to select the element by `id` as per your code `document.getElementById()`

Solution: `document.getElementById()` as the property named it searches for the `id` attribute in the element so you need to provide `id` to the element

```
<button id="uniqueID">Kaufen</button>
```

and then selecting it with,

```
const button = document.getElementById('uniqueID');
```

To Learn more about selectors in `JavaScript` you can check [This Link](https://attacomsian.com/blog/getting-dom-elements-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try id instead of data-id.

```html
<button id="g/incider/perry">Kaufen</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var button = document.getElementById('g/incider/perry');
  button.addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() { 
      alert("test");      
    },
    false
  );
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use data-id for some reason you have to use the getAttribute() function to get the value of an attribute otherwise just stick with id.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('g/incider/perry');
button.addEventListener('click', () =>
alert("test");
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="g/incider/perry">Kaufen</button>
```